# Some domain classes are not cached in Grails 1.3.9 and EhCache

Tags: grails, ehcache, grails-domain-class

I am maintaining a Grails 1.3.9 application that uses EhCache second-level cache.

Most of the domain classes are cached as expected (they have cache true set in domain classes, named queries are set to use the cache).

EhCache is configured to cache queries also.

When inspecting the cache with the Melody plugin I noticed that two very often used domain classes don't have any entries in the cache. Other domain classes are cached as expected.

What could be the cause that these domain classes are not cached?

Comment: Configuration mistake, unfair evictions ... plenty of things can go wrong. Hard to say though with this level of information.

Comment: @LouisJacomet: I know that my question is a bit vague but honestly I do not know how to analyse this. How could I detect unfair eviciton?

Comment: You need to add configuration information - cache config, hibernate config (assuming that's what second level refers to), etc ... For unfair evictions, you could register a cache event listener. But that would apply only if all entities end up in the same cache, unlikely with hibernate 2LC usual configs.